# How to merge additional options to jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my quest to improve my jquery/ javascript skills, I'm trying to refactor and clean up some repetitive code. What is the best way to add additional options to a function?

Using Select2 as an example, I have a default function and occasionally need to add additional options

```
$(".selectable").select2({
  theme: "classic"
});

$(".selectable .placeholder").select2({
  theme: "classic"
  placeholder: "Select a state",
  allowClear: true
});

$(".selectable .taggable").select2({
  theme: "classic"
  tags: true,
  tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
})
```

This is a little contrived and the actual code is much more complex, but hopefully this serves to illustrate that there is a default condition, and occasionally extra options are added.

I'm looking for something like

```
$(".selectable").select2({
  theme: "classic"
});

if $(".selectable .taggable").length
  $(".selectable").merge_options({
  tags: true
  tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
  })
```

Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: ask to plugin author.

Comment: Use `$.extend` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/